# Linux TCP-packet-Sniffing with eBPF-KProbe, reading package-content from iov_iter not working

Tags: c, linux, tcp, linux-kernel, ebpf

I'm trying to evaluate the content of in and outgoing tcp packages with eBPF kprobes using libbpf. Therefore I attached a Kprobe to tcp_sendmsg and tcp_recvmsg.
As of my knowledge, the package payload is in the second parameter struct msghdr *msg ->(struct iov_iter*) msg_iter ->(struct iovec*) iov ->(void*) iov_base.

when I try to read the length of the iovec (iov_length) it is 1, while msg_iter->count has the correct length of the payload.

Reading the payload-length from iov_base works, but the data then seems to be corrupt.
I guess that the data has to be fully flushed into the iov_iter before reading.

How can I read the package-payload correctly inside a kprobe?

eBPF-kprobe on tcp_sendmsg to reproduce this behaviour:

```
#include"vmlinux.h"
#include<bpf/bpf_helpers.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_tracing.h>

const char fmt_info1[] = "segs: %d, offset: %d ,count:%d\n";
const char fmt_info2[] = "iov_length: %d, read_length: %d, data-readsuccess: %d\n";
const char fmt_notify_data[] = "iter_type: %d, Data: ";
const char fmt_data[] = "%02x ";
const char fmt_end[] = "\n";
unsigned char databuf[256];

SEC("kprobe/tcp_sendmsg")
int probe_tcp_sendmsg(struct pt_regs *ctx){
    struct msghdr *msg = (struct msghdr *)PT_REGS_PARM2(ctx);
    struct iov_iter *iter= &(msg->msg_iter);
    struct iovec *iter_data = (struct iovec *)&(iter->iov);
    int read_success=-1;
    long unsigned int iov_seg_count;//count of iovec's
    unsigned char iov_type;//0 is iter_iovec
    unsigned long iov_count;//total data length in iter
    unsigned long iov_length;//length of current iovec
    unsigned long iov_offset;//iovec's to skip in iter
    unsigned long read_length;//final length in the data buffer

    read_success=bpf_probe_read(&iov_type, sizeof(unsigned char), &(iter->iter_type));
    if(read_success!=0) {
        return 0;
    } 
    read_success=bpf_probe_read(&iov_seg_count, sizeof(long unsigned int), &(iter->nr_segs));
    if(read_success!=0) {
        return 0;
    } 
   read_success=bpf_probe_read(&iov_count, sizeof(unsigned long), &(iter->count));
    if(read_success!=0) {
        return 0;
    } 
    read_success=bpf_probe_read(&iov_offset, sizeof(unsigned long), &(iter->iov_offset));
    if(read_success!=0) {
        return 0;
    } 

    void* startaddress;
    read_success=bpf_probe_read(&startaddress, sizeof(void*), &(iter_data->iov_base));
    if(read_success!=0){
        return 0;
    }
    
    
    read_success=bpf_probe_read(&iov_length, sizeof(size_t), &(iter_data->iov_len));
    if(read_success!=0){
        return 0;
    }
    
    if(iov_length< 256){//change against iov_count
        read_length=iov_length;//change against iov_count
    }else{
        read_length=256;
    } 
    read_success=bpf_probe_read(databuf, read_length, startaddress);
    bpf_trace_printk(fmt_info1, sizeof(fmt_info1),iov_seg_count, iov_offset, iov_count);
    bpf_trace_printk(fmt_info2, sizeof(fmt_info2),iov_length, read_length, read_success);
    bpf_trace_printk(fmt_notify_data, sizeof(fmt_notify_data), iov_type);
    for(unsigned long i=0;i<read_length;++i){
        bpf_trace_printk(fmt_data,sizeof(fmt_data), databuf[i]);
    } 
    bpf_trace_printk(fmt_end, sizeof(fmt_end));

    return 0;
}

char LICENSE[] SEC("license") = "Dual BSD/GPL";
```

vmlinux.h is created with:
`bpftool btf dump file /sys/kernel/btf/vmlinux format c > vmlinux.h`
Then the ebpf programm is compiled with:
`clang -g -O3 -target bpf -D__TARGET_ARCH_x86 -c bpf_ip_tcp.c -o bpf_ip_tcp.o`
Then the skelleton is created with:
`bpftool gen skeleton bpf_ip_tcp.o name bpf_ip_tcp > bpf_ip_tcp.h`
Then the loader is compiled with:
`clang -Wall -Wextra -g3 main.c -o ebpf-example  -lbpf`
My loader looks like this:

```
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include "bpf_ip_tcp.h"
int main(){
    struct rlimit rlim_new = {
        .rlim_cur   = RLIM_INFINITY,
        .rlim_max   = RLIM_INFINITY,
    };
    if (setrlimit(RLIMIT_MEMLOCK, &rlim_new)) {
        exit(1);
    }
    struct bpf_ip_tcp *skel = bpf_ip_tcp__open();
    bpf_ip_tcp__load(skel);
    bpf_ip_tcp__attach(skel); 
    while(1==1){}; 
    return 0;
}
```

Results:
Output in `cat /sys/kernel/tracing/trace_pipe` while using wget:

```
...
wget-22674   [006] d...1 46410.754999: bpf_trace_printk: segs: 1, offset: 0 ,count:400
wget-22674   [006] d...1 46410.755059: bpf_trace_printk: iov_length: 1, read_length: 1, data-readsuccess: 0
wget-22674   [006] d...1 46410.755061: bpf_trace_printk: iter_type: 0, Data: 
wget-22674   [006] d...1 46410.755061: bpf_trace_printk: 40
...
```

Expected is either multiple segments or iov_length equal to count.

System: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, Kernel: 5.15.0 .